# Python Qt+OpenGL drawing region bug

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt4, pyopengl

I have simple code for OpenGl, but the region of drawing doesn't display propperly, it's about 100x30 when i want ot be on full size. However my OpenGl widget has propper clear behavior. How can i fix this?

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL
import sys
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

try:
    from OpenGL import GL
except ImportError:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(None, "OpenGL hellogl",
            "PyOpenGL must be installed to run this example.")
    sys.exit(1)


class Ui_Form(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(700, 532)


        self.openGLWidget = GLWidget(Form)
        self.openGLWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10 , 10, 512, 512))
        self.openGLWidget.setObjectName("openGLWidget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))

class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(GLWidget, self).__init__(parent)


    def initializeGL(self):
        GL.glClearColor(0,255,0,255)

    def paintGL(self):


        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glLoadIdentity()

        gluOrtho2D(0, 1, 0, 1);

        glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        glVertex2i(0, 0)
        glVertex2i(1000, 0)
        glVertex2i(1000, 1000)
        glVertex2i(0, 1000)
        glEnd();

        glFlush()




if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui_Form()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried to change glOrtho and add some glut functions but no result. Also i tried add matrix multiplication to scale it, seems like there is some wrong values for display region.

[image]

Comment: @Rabbid76  for now i just want my rectangle break this 30x80 area. yes i draw 1000x1000 rectangle in 1x1 area, but why it's 30x80 on my widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up the viewport size. See [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glViewport.xml):

> `void glViewport( GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height);`
>
> `x`, `y` Specify the lower left corner of the viewport rectangle, in pixels. The initial value is (0,0).
>   `width`, `height` Specify the width and height of the viewport.
>
> `glViewport` specifies the affine transformation of `x` and `y` from normalized device coordinates to window coordinates.

Your code should look somehow like this:

```
def paintGL(self):

    width = 512
    height = 512

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2i(0, 0)
    glVertex2i(width, 0)
    glVertex2i(width, height)
    glVertex2i(0, height)
    glEnd()

    glFlush()
```

Note, in OpenGL there is one matrix stack for each matrix mode (See [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). The matrix modes are `GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION`, and `GL_TEXTURE`. So you should set up the projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`)  and the model view matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`), because each vertex is transformed by the modelview matrix and the projection matrix.

See futher [QT + OPENGL CODE EXAMPLE](http://programanddesign.com/cpp/qt-opengl-code-example/)

By the way, the parameters of [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) are floating point values in the range [0, 1]. Change the methode `initializeGL`:

```
def initializeGL(self):
    GL.glClearColor(0,1,0,1)
```